# SWIFT: performance of uppercaseString

Tags: string, performance, swift, nsstring

I have a large file (25 MB) of text. I read it into a NSString var. I want to use "uppercaseString" to convert every char to upper case. But the function in so terribly slow, it needs minutes.
Any tip to get it work much faster?

Added code:

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("GERMANU", ofType: "txt") {
    var error: NSError?
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: NSDataReadingOptions(), error: &error) {           
        if let datastring = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding) {
            var upper = datastring.uppercaseString
 ...
```

That's the code which works, but is slow. Only last row needs all the time.

Comment: Which takes longer - reading the string from the file or converting it to uppercase?  If the conversion to uppercase is instantaneous, maybe the performance is still 'terribly slow'.

Comment: Reading the string is done within a tick. That's the strange thing! Changing the string within memory needs so much time. Even splitting the data into seperate strings and inserting them in an array is much much faster. So there must be a behaviour which needs to avoided.

Comment: It did it. See above. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like a poor library implementation. Using `NSString.uppercaseString()` is realy fast (half a second). So I will use this, but I'm developing in Swift because I like the language. So I don't want to switch back to old stuff.

Answer (score 1):

`String::uppercaseString` is instantaneous; creating the string is not.

```
 # Long time
 12> var st : String = "".join(Array(count:25000000, repeatedValue: "a")) 
st: String = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa..."

 # Short time
 13> st.uppercaseString
$R8: String = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA..."
```

Given that you are using the `Roman` encoding, it is possible that the conversion to uppercase is non-trivial.  Perhaps you can try another encoding (if any others are appropriate)?  You might try the `init?(... usedEncoding ...)` variant and invoke `fastestEncoding` on the result to explore a bit.

Note: you can create a Swift string directly from a file with a particular encoding using:

```
if let datastring = String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: ... , error: &error) {
  var upper = datastring.uppercaseString
}
```

Comment: But that's exactly what I did. And that's slow:    
var upper = datastring.uppercaseString